# Can't get value of existing div of webpage

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I've been testing the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for a while now, but don't understand the following problem.

Looks like I can only get a value with `//body` as XPATH, not with any other XPATH value. I already tested with several other websites, but always getting the same `Nothing` result.

- **Website**: http://www.yosoyke.be.
- **Wanted**: all `li` elements of the `div` with `id` equals to `navigation`.

My code:

```
Dim page As HtmlWeb = New HtmlWeb
Dim doc As HtmlDocument = page.Load("http://www.yosoyke.be")

Dim col As HtmlNodeCollection =
  doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//DIV[@id='navigation']/UL/LI")

For Each node As HtmlNode In col
  Console.WriteLine(node.OuterHtml)
Next
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DocumentNode.SelectNodes` (XPATH) is case sensitive by default. This works:

```
Dim col As HtmlNodeCollection =
  doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='navigation']/ul/li")
```

Also see these:

- [HTML Agility Pack Parsing With Upper & Lower Case Tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5779664/897326)
- [HtmlAgilityPack XPath case ignoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147825/htmlagilitypack-xpath-case-ignoring)

> when you use its XPATH feature, you must use tags written in lower case. It means the "//body" expression will match BODY, Body and body, and "//BODY" will match nothing.